# How to avoid deep copy when using groupby in polars rust?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a dataset where I need to do groupby operation on different columns. Here is minimal working code using polars version "0.21.1"

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_lazy::prelude::*;
use polars::df;

fn main(){
  let df = df![
    "x1" => ["a", "b", "c", "a"],
    "x2" => ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
    "y" => [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ].unwrap();

  let lf: LazyFrame = df.lazy();

  let out1 = groupby_x1(&lf);
  println!("{:?}", out1.collect());
  let out2 = groupby_x2(&lf);
  println!("{:?}", out2.collect());

}

fn  groupby_x1(lf: &LazyFrame) -> LazyFrame {
  let lf1: LazyFrame = lf.clone().groupby([col("x1")]).agg([
    col("y").sum().alias("y_sum"),
  ]);
  lf1
}

fn  groupby_x2(lf: &LazyFrame) -> LazyFrame {
  let lf1: LazyFrame = lf.clone().groupby([col("x2")]).agg([
    col("y").sum().alias("y_sum"),
  ]);
  lf1
}
```

But in the code I am making deep copies of whole lazyframe `lf` (using `lf.clone()`. How can I avoid that? If I replace `lf.clone()` with `lf` in functions `groupby_x1` and `groupby_x2` I get following error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*lf` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:22:24
   |
22 |   let lf1: LazyFrame = lf.groupby([col("x1")]).agg([
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*lf` has type `polars_lazy::frame::LazyFrame`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*lf` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:29:24
   |
29 |   let lf1: LazyFrame = lf.groupby([col("x2")]).agg([
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*lf` has type `polars_lazy::frame::LazyFrame`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `polars_try` due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polars `Series` are a newtype around `Arc<Vec<ArrowRef>>`. When you clone a `DataFrame` only the reference count of the `Arc` is incremented.

In other words, polars never does deep clones. Clones of a `DataFrame` are super cheap.

Comment: Hey @ritchie46, does the same apply to LazyFrame? ie is LazyFrame clone also relatively cheap?

Comment: This is essentially the same for `LazyFrame`, with a caveat of the size of the logical plan. see https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9591

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.LazyFrame.html#), `LazyFrame`:

> Lazy abstraction over an eager DataFrame. It really is an abstraction
> over a logical plan. The methods of this struct will incrementally
> modify a logical plan until output is requested (via collect)

Meaning **there is no deep copy of the Dataframe**, nothing is performed until you actually collect it.

Hence you have two options:

1. You keep copying them if you want to keep the original plan intact
2. You take ownership of the plan `groupby_x1(lf: LazyFrame)`, and let the user of the function deal with the need of actually cloning the original plan if needed.